# How to get height of div which contains dynamically added image?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a little script that add images to some columns. I would like it to add images to the smallest column. But when I try to get the height of the columns it always return 30px (surely because the images are not loaded yet)

Here is some code :

```
<div id="diaporama-col1" class="col-xs-4">

</div>
<div id="diaporama-col2" class="col-xs-4">

</div>
<div id="diaporama-col3" class="col-xs-4">

</div>
```

.

```
var listImgDiaporama=["resources/img/img-1.jpg", "resources/img/img-2.jpg", "resources/img/img-3.jpg", "resources/img/img-4.jpg", "resources/img/img-5.jpg", "resources/img/img-6.jpg", "resources/img/img-7.jpg", "resources/img/img-8.jpg", "resources/img/img-9.jpg", "resources/img/img-10.jpg", "resources/img/img-11.jpg"];
function addImgToDiaporama() {


    for (i = 0; i < listImgDiaporama.length; i++) {

        var col1Height = $("#diaporama-col1").height();
        var col2Height = $("#diaporama-col2").height();
        var col3Height = $("#diaporama-col3").height();

        if (col1Height <= col2Height && col1Height <= col3Height) {
            $("#diaporama-col1").append("<img src=\"" + listImgDiaporama[i] + "\"/>")
        } else if (col2Height <= col1Height && col2Height <= col3Height) {
            $("#diaporama-col2").append("<img src=\"" + listImgDiaporama[i] + "\"/>")
        } else {
            $("#diaporama-col3").append("<img src=\"" + listImgDiaporama[i] + "\"/>")
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to make this work ?

Comment: sorry, question is a bit unclear to me. divs are same height, why do you need to see smallest col?

Comment: Are you trying to order the images depending on their height?

Comment: You can't get height of an image until it is loaded. Your loop will have completed long before the first one has even loaded. Probably need to preload your images....then do whatever it is you are trying to accomplish

Comment: I was not really clear sorry. So i have images of differents sizes and i would like my 3 columns to be as equals as possible. So i want to go through and add the image to the smallest column

Comment: The way I see it, you have equally distributed the width and the height of the columns should be same since there is no content loaded yet. So all 3 columns are the same at initial stage. To make it work you have to define the columns to some initial values at first.

Comment: But you empty those elements first. They would then be whatever height is set due to css. Objective is not very clear. Create a demo

Comment: @charlietfl Yeah ! I think you understood my problem, i will try to preload the images (I'll delete the emptying thing)

Comment: Use css for equal height columns - no need for jquery, if you want to go the jquery route, you seem to get the height before you append the image, what you need to do is preload them on document ready, then get the height after you append them

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this, where we compare the height of the columns, figure out the shortest and append the image to it.

Hope this is helpful (helps to view in fullscreen or at https://jsfiddle.net/j9v5uwf2/1/

```js
$('#addImage').click(function(){
  
  $shortest_column = getShortestColumn();
  $image = getRandImage();

  $($shortest_column).append($image);

});



function getShortestColumn(){

  var shortest_column = null;
  var shortest = 999999999;
  $(".column").each(function(){
    var height = $(this).height();
    if(height < shortest){
       shortest = height;
       shortest_column = $(this);  
    }    
  });

  return shortest_column;
}


function getRandImage(){
 $rn = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50) + 1
  if ($rn = 1){$image = "<img src='http://lorempixel.com/200/100/'>";}
  else {$image = "<img src='http://lorempixel.com/200/150/'>";}
  
  return $image;
}
```

```css
.column {
  width:30%;
  margin-left:1%;
  margin-right:1%;
  float:left;
  background: #222;
  text-align: center;
}
img {
  max-width:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div>
  <center><button id="addImage">Add Image</button></center>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="column" id="column1">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/100/">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/150/">
</div>
<div class="column" id="column2">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/150/">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/150/">
</div>
<div class="column" id="column3">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/150/" alt="">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/100/" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your images are all being added in one js call (e.g. its just looping through an array of images, rather than on click of a button)

I have added a delay between each image just for demo purposes, feel free to remove it for live.

https://jsfiddle.net/g6L7mbp7/3/

```js
$numberOfImages = 5

// Create an array of varying sized images
$images = [];
i = 0;
while (i < $numberOfImages ){
 $images[i] = getRandImage();
  i++;
}

// click button to bein inserting images
$('#addImage').click(function(){

 $($images).each(function(index,image){
    
    
    //remove the timeout bit for live, just here to demonstrate that its adding the images to the right columns
    setTimeout(function () {
    
      $shortest_column = getShortestColumn();
        $($shortest_column).append(image);
        
    }, index*500);
   
    
 });
 
});

function addImage($image){
  $shortest_column = getShortestColumn();
  $($shortest_column).append($image);
}

function getShortestColumn(){

  var shortest_column = null;
  var shortest = 999999999;
  $(".column").each(function(){
    var height = $(this).height();
    if(height < shortest){
       shortest = height;
       shortest_column = $(this);  
    }    
  });

  return shortest_column;
}


   function getRandImage(){
   $rn = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1
   if ($rn % 2){$image = "<img src='http://lorempixel.com/200/100/'>";}
   else {$image = "<img src='http://lorempixel.com/200/200/'>";}
  
   return $image;
}
```

```css
.column {
  width:30%;
  margin-left:1%;
  margin-right:1%;
  float:left;
  background: #222;
  text-align: center;
}
img {
  max-width:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <center><button id="addImage">Add Images</button></center>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="column" id="column1">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/100/">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/150/">
</div>
<div class="column" id="column2">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/150/">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/150/">
</div>
<div class="column" id="column3">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/150/" alt="">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/100/" alt="">
</div>
```